# how can I make the DOM work with ejs and Mysql

Tags: html, mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I want to compare "test" with "angendaOficina".

- test is a DOM element.
- angendaOficina is a table in Mysql database.

When I run the code it tells me that test is not defined and I understand that it is because of the <%%> that I can, but if I remove it, it tells me that document is not defined.

```
<form name="formulario">
<div><input name="busqueda" placeholder="BUSCAR" required type="text" autofocus></div>
</form>
<div><button id="btn">BUSCAR</button></div>
 
<script>
function operation() {
    var test = document.formulario.busqueda.value;
    <% for (var i = 0; i < angendaOficina.length; i++){%>
        <%if(angendaOficina[i].carpeta == test){
            console.log("MATCH");
        }else{
            console.log("NO MATCH");
        }
        %>
    <%}%>
}
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
btn.addEventListener('click', operation, true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't really do exactly what you wanna do, but i can at least help you to solve your problem.

You should not use EJS to import your database like this.
If you want to use your DB data like this, import it in the HTML JavaScript using GET requests.

To do requests you can either use a module like jQuery (which i don't recommend but it is surely the most known) or use the defaults XMLHttpRequest.

You can handle thoses requests in your express server like this :

```js
expressApp.get("/getDatabase", (req, res) => { // "/getDatabase" is the url you wanna GET request.
  res.json({
    data: dbObject // "dbObject" is your DB data object.
  })
})
```

Then, when you do a request to "/getDatabase" you will get a JSON object that contains data as your database data.